# Cordova storing images in localstorage

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

I'm creating a cordova app targetting iOS 6.1 and above. I need to store json data with images. As you guessed the images will be stored as base-64 string. I need to store dozens of images and in this case is it better go with localStorage or filestorage. Is there any size limit in Cordova's localstorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova uses browser's native implementation of `localStorage` where available, using its own only where `localStorage` is not available. Generally, limit of `localStorage` is unknown as it depends on browser and user settings. There is an arbitrary limit of 5 MB in [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space), which equals 2.5 MB of 2 byte-encoded text, which equals roughly 1.8 MB of binary data.

`FileStorage` seems more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using localForage, you could store the image as a base64 string or even a Blob.
http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob